# maven effective pom shows plugin thats not defined

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a problem with my effective pom file.
I am running a multi-module project.
I have a main pom and base project pom.
My main pom does not contain a maven-release-plugin dependency,
however the base project pom.
I defined the plugin maven-release-plugin in the base project pom,
with a version 2.5.3.
My effective pom from the main project shows, however, with the maven release plugin as a plugin in version 2.3.2.
I have the dependency: tree show but does not show the maven release plugin. Simply not available. I can not explain it.

How can that be the main effective pom shows me the maven release plugin in a version that I have not defined?

My real problem is that Jenkins uses the maven-release-plugin version to build my release. However, this raises errors and I can not build correctly. Jenkins uses the first defined plugin version to build my release.

The mvn dependency:resolve-plugins did not show any maven-release-plugin with version 2.3.2

Here are my main pom

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.project</groupId>
<artifactId>ROOT</artifactId>
<version>9.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>BASE</module>
</modules>

<profiles>
    <!-- Arquillian WildFly managed profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>id</id>

        <properties>
            <gitname>user</gitname>
            <gitpw>password</gitpw>
            <project.scm.id>git</project.scm.id>
        </properties>

        <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>m1ss-nexus</id>
                <name>Release Repository</name>
                <url>url</url>
                <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            </repository>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>m1ss-nexus</id>
                <name>Snapshots Repository</name>
                <url>url</url>
                <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            </snapshotRepository>
        </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:repository</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:repository</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Here are my effective main pom with the maven-release-plugin 2.3.2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>ROOT</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>BASE</module>
  </modules>
  <scm>
    <connection>connection</connection>
    <developerConnection>connection</developerConnection>
  </scm>
  <properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd_HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <sonar.checkstyle.filters>&lt;module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">&lt;property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE:OFF\: ([\w\|]+)" />&lt;property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE:ON\: ([\w\|]+)" />&lt;property name="checkFormat" value="$1" />&lt;/module>&lt;module name="SuppressionFilter">&lt;property name="file" value="${workspace}/sonar_configs/checkstyle_suppressions.xml" />&lt;/module>&lt;module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">&lt;property name="commentFormat" value="Suppress checkstyle (\w+)" />&lt;property name="influenceFormat" value="1" />&lt;/module></sonar.checkstyle.filters>
    <was.appsrv>C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer</was.appsrv>
    <maindir>C:\IBM\RSA95</maindir>
    <sonar.jacoco.excludes>**/*Test.*:**/*BE.*:**/*CType.*:**/*TO.*:**/*CTO.*:**/*Exception.*:**/*DT.*:**/constants/*.*:**/datatype/*.*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
    <timestamp>20180927_1336</timestamp>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <was.appsrv.plugins>C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins</was.appsrv.plugins>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <version_minor>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}</version_minor>
    <was.basedir>C:\IBM\WebSphere</was.basedir>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>m1ss-nexus</id>
      <url>url</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>url repo maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>url repo maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target</directory>
    <finalName>ROOT-9.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\develop\workspace\moss\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profileid</id>
      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>m1ss-nexus</id>
          <name>Release Repository</name>
          <url>url</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
          <id>m1ss-nexus</id>
          <name>Snapshots Repository</name>
          <url>url</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>
      <properties>
        <project.scm.id>git</project.scm.id>
        <gitname>user</gitname>
        <gitpw>password</gitpw>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Here are my base pom with maven-release-plugin 2.5.3

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.project</groupId>
<artifactId>BASE</artifactId>
<version>9.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>de.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>ROOT</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>   

<modules>
    <module>core/SRV-API-BASE</module>
    <module>core/SRV-IMPL-BASE</module>
    <module>core/DLG-BASE</module>
    <module>components/DLG-WAR</module>
    <module>components/DLG-ECOM-WAR</module>
    <module>core/DLG-EAR</module>
    <module>core/SRV-EAR</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.50</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.oval</groupId>
            <artifactId>oval</artifactId>
            <version>1.84</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.capgemini.psp.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>psp-server-plain-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21-SOE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.capgemini.psp.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>psp-server-plain-env</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21-SOE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.capgemini.psp.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>psp-server-plain-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21-M1SS</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.capgemini.psp.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>psp-server-plain-ejb-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21-SOE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdm.quasar</groupId>
            <artifactId>QuasarComponent</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.32</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail-impl</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ws.prereq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsfportlet</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies aus dem Websphere-Server. Sie ersetzen WAS Server Runtime Bibliotheken -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/gen/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>parse-version</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>parse-version</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>native2ascii-utf8-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**\/*Txt.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <branchName>master-release</branchName>
                <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>    
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>              
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.10.0</version>
           <configuration>
                <tag>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</tag>
                <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>password</password>      
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>1.10.0</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <tag>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</tag>
                    <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                    <username>user</username>
                    <password>password</password>      
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>                
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ajdtVersion>1.5</ajdtVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                       <version>1.10.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the Maven superpom (comparable to java.lang.Object, it is inheritd by all poms), see http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html